# C# How to manipulate JSON using SelectToken

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON in `string jsonContent` 
First I have to check if it is JObject or JArray

```
 private static bool IsJObject(string jsonContent)
        {
            return JToken.Parse(jsonContent) is JObject;
        }
```

Then:

```
if (IsJObject(jsonContent))
            {
                var jObject = ParseJObject(jsonContent);
                return GetFieldValueFromJObject(jObject, fieldPath);
            }
            else
            {
                var jArray = ParseJArray(jsonContent);
                return GetFieldValueFromJArray(jArray, fieldPath);
            }
```

How to Get Field Value from JObject using JsonPath eg. "name"
How to Get Field Value from JArray using JsonPath eg. "[3].name"
How to Change Field Value from JObject and JArray?
How to Remove Field from JObject and JArray?

My code for get:

```
private static string GetFieldValueFromJObject(JObject jObject, string fieldPath)
        {
            return (string)jObject.SelectToken($"$.{fieldPath}");
        }

        private static string GetFieldValueFromJArray(JArray jArray, string fieldPath)
        {
            return (string)jArray.SelectToken($"$.{fieldPath}");
        }
```

Object json:

```
{
        "email": "testtest@fsafsf.com",
        "password": "testestest",
        "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
        "username": "Kamren",
        "address": {
            "street": "Skiles Walks",
            "suite": "Suite 351",
            "city": "Roscoeview",
            "zipcode": "33263",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-31.8129",
                "lng": "62.5342"
            }
        },
        "phone": "(254)954-1289",
        "website": "demarco.info",
        "company": {
            "name": "Keebler LLC",
            "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
            "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
        }   
}
```

Array json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test123",
        "username": "test",
        "phone": "4636346",
        "website": "sdgsdgsdg",
        "company": {
            "name": "sdgsdg",
            "catchPhrase": "dgsdg",
            "bs": "sdgsdg"
        },
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "email": "testuser02@ddsfsdf.com",
        "password": "$2a$10$IIoTzjHSA07ZcWIbXRfv/OQhkxSDy/LHXQHdpcwMPgYPm97uTLwuG",
        "id": 3,
        "name": "testest1",
        "username": "Samantha",
        "address": {
            "street": "Douglas Extension",
            "suite": "Suite 847",
            "city": "McKenziehaven",
            "zipcode": "59590-4157",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-68.6102",
                "lng": "-47.0653"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
        "website": "ramiro.info",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
            "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
            "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample json you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Intro:
JArray has list of JObjects, both JArray and JObject can have JProperty.
JObject can be used as JProperty.
JArray, JObject, JProperty all derive from JToken

To get value from JObject use

```
jObject[propertyName]
```

To get value from within array

```
jArray[index][propertyName]
```

Changing from jObject to jArray or vice versa doesn't make sense, it is jObject OR jArray, it cannot be same, but keep in mind they both derive from JToken.

To delete item

```
foreach(JProperty prop in jObj)
        {
            if (prop.Name == "your prop name")
                prop.Remove();
        }
```

Comment: I dont want to use [index][propertyName]
Only JsonPath like: address.street or [3].name

Comment: Than try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);